# Limit the number of rows returned - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I'm trying to limit the number of rows returned from a query. This is the code i'm using.

```
$min = ($id2-1)*16;
$max = $id2*16;

$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anunt WHERE masina = 2 ORDER BY anuntID DESC LIMIT $min, $max") or die(mysql_error());
```

ID2 is a value parsed from the link. So when ID2 is 2 for example, the query should have a limit from 16 to 32 - so a total of 16 entries. But my problem is that the query is returning me 32 entries. It's like it's jumping over the '$min' value. I quad checked everything and in the end, that query seems the problem.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anunt WHERE masina = 2 ORDER BY anuntID DESC LIMIT $min, $max") or die(mysql_error());
```

by this:

```
$records = $max - $min;
$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anunt WHERE masina = 2 ORDER BY anuntID DESC LIMIT $records, $min") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is `LIMIT start_index, amount`, not `LIMIT start_index, end_index`

Answer (score 3):

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

You pass row_count=32.
Check [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Answer (score 1):

use LIMIT

your query LIMIT FROM TO